# Send push Notification with FCM on iOS

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I tried to send push notification to my Cordova iOS App.

I used the plugin [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm)

For my Android app it's working perfectly, the problem is for iOS, my curl request returns:

> InvalidApnsCredential

I have upload my Apns key on FCM and this key work because I've try to send a push notification with just Apns  and it's work fine my app receive the notification.

Here is the APNS script that works: http://thrysoee.dk/apns/

Here my PHP curl script with FCM which works with Android but not iOS:

```php
$pushUrl    = "FCM_PUSH_URL"; //https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
$key        = "SERVER_KEY";//Server key get in FCM console
$ch         = curl_init($pushUrl);
$headers    = [];

$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization:key=' . $key;
$data  = array(
    "notification" => array(
        "title"         => "Bonjour le monde !",
        "body"          => "Notif de test",
        //"click_action"  =>"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
        "icon"          => "fcm_push_icon",
    ),
    "data" => array(
      'msg'     => 'hello',
      'msg2'    => 'world'
    ),
    "to"        => "MY_IOS_REGISTER_TOKEN"//token get on my ipad with the getToken method of cordova plugin,
    "priority" => "high",
);

$json_data = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($res,true) . "</pre>"; exit;//{"multicast_id":xxxx,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidApnsCredential"}]}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally find the problem . On firebase console use **allways** your apple teamID for the app prefix even if your appID have a prefixID different of your teamID

Comment: Could you share an example for this?